# How do I tranfer contacts from iphone to gmail?

Tags: gmail

How do I transfer my contacts from iPhone to Gmail ? I am not sure which is the correct site to ask this question, because it is a non-technical question. Can anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but the primary way is actually built into iOS. I gathered the information [from this link where](http://support.google.com/a/users/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) there is a good comprehensive run down of all the details in setting up a Gmail account and getting the syncing going.

Set up Gmail using the Exchange trick so that contact syncing will continue in the future:

> 1. Open the Settings application on your device's home screen.
> 2. Open Mail, Contacts, Calendars.
> 3. Press Add Account....
> 4. Select Microsoft Exchange
> 5. In the Email field, enter your full Google Account email address.
> 6. Enter your Google Account password as the Password.
> 7. Press Next at the top of your screen.
> 8. Enter m.google.com in the Server field.
> 9. Leave the Domain field blank.
> 10. Enter the user email address as the Username.
> 11. Press Next at the top of your screen again.
> 12. Select the Google services (Mail, Calendar, and Contacts) you want to sync.

And then to transfer your contacts to Google it looks like you will need to transfer your current contacts to iTunes:

> If you have all your contacts on your device and want to import them into Google, you can synchronize your Google Contacts with iTunes. All Contacts and Calendars that you sync with iTunes will be put into the On My iPhone Contacts and Calendar groups on your phone. iOS currently doesn't allow you to move Contacts or Calendar events from the On My iPhone groups to the Google Sync groups.

Note that you will have to turn **off** iCloud contacts sync if you sync with iTunes. It won't let you transfer that to iTunes otherwise.

---

For another option [you can use this app to transfer your contacts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-sync-for-google-gmail/id454390333?mt=8) to Gmail, and manage syncing.

---

This looked [like a good tutorial](http://transfer-iphone-contacts.blogspot.com/p/transfer-iphone-contacts-via-gmail.html) on setting up the sync using Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method:

1. On the iPhone go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add account > Gmail
2. Enter your Gmail account credentials
3. Toggle the Contacts switch to ON

All iPhone contacts will be synced to your Gmail account. If you were syncing the iPhone contacts to iCloud at the time of syncing with Gmail, look this tutorial to [transfer iphone cloud contacts between accounts](http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-iphone-contacts-between-cloud-accounts/) instead.